# iPhone : integer overflow in expression

Tags: iphone, nsnumber, nstimeinterval

I get integer overflow in expression for NSTimerInterval, which is really a double.

```
NSTimerInterval paymentTermsInMilliSeconds = 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
```

What's the best way to handle timer interval in iPhone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use,

```
NSTimerInterval paymentTermsInMilliSeconds = 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000.0;
```

Hope, will solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely caused because the calculation is being performed on integers, which is giving an integer result. Try instead to use double values.

EDIT: I just checked, and this is exactly what is happening. If you change your calculation to: `NSTimeInterval paymentTermsInMilliSeconds = 30.0 * 24.0 * 60.0 * 60.0 * 1000.0;`, then the code gives the correct value of "2592000000". Otherwise, you end up with an overflow and a result of "-1702967296".

Answer (score 1):

You probably mean `NSTimeInterval`. This is usually a time interval in seconds. To use with milliseconds use 0.001 seconds for milliseconds.